# unity board game player movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a feature where the movement of my player is controlled by a "Roll" button, which acts as a random number generator. The idea is for the player to advance across the cubes in accordance with the number produced by this generator.

To implement this, I've equipped my player with both a Rigidbody and a Collider. I attempted to link the GameObject, which carries the relevant script, to the button's "On Click" event, but it doesn't seem to be functioning as expected. Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions for this issue?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MovePlayerOnButtonPress : MonoBehaviour
{
 public GameObject BoardGamePiece_Blue; // Assign your player object here
    public Text rollResultText; // Assign your roll result UI Text here
    public float moveDistancePerUnit = 1.0f; // Distance to move per roll unit

    private bool isRollButtonPressed = false;
    private int rollNumber = 0;

    private int currentPosition = 0;

     public Transform[] spaces;
     public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;

    public void OnRollButtonPressed()
    {
        rollNumber = Random.Range(1, 7); // Simulating a dice roll (1 to 6)
        rollResultText.text = rollNumber.ToString();
        isRollButtonPressed = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isRollButtonPressed)
        {
            MovePlayerByRollNumber();
            isRollButtonPressed = false;

             Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
        currentPosition.x += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = currentPosition;
        }
    }

    private void MovePlayerByRollNumber()
    {
        Vector3 moveDirection = BoardGamePiece_Blue.transform.forward * moveDistancePerUnit * rollNumber;
        BoardGamePiece_Blue.transform.position += moveDirection;
    }

    public void MovePlayer(int steps)
    {
        // Calculate the new position.
        currentPosition += steps;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are new to programming.
It would be great if you specified what you mean by "not as expected".

By how you described it the most probable cause is that you just linked the game object of the script, and forgot to link the `OnRollButtonPressed()`.
So try doing that, but i've also noticed that the `MovePlayer()` isn't being called anywhere while you maybe want it to be called, and that in this:

```
public GameObject BoardGamePiece_Blue; // Assign your player object here
public Text rollResultText; // Assign your roll result UI Text here
public float moveDistancePerUnit = 1.0f; // Distance to move per roll unit

private bool isRollButtonPressed = false;
private int rollNumber = 0;

private int currentPosition = 0;

 public Transform[] spaces;
 public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
```

Part of the code you declare the variable `currentPosition` as `int` but in other parts of the code its being used as `Vector3`, and that in `MovePlayer()` you are trying to add a number to a `Vector3` (if you intend for `currentPosition` to be `Vector3`).

If you want to add a value to a `Vector3` variable, you can do this instead

```
Vector3 example;

example.x = 3
example.y = 4
example.z = 1

example = example + new Vector3(6, 10, 7);
```

which will result  in x value of it being 9, y value of it being 14, and z value of it being 7.

If this doesnt solve your issues - provide more information on what exactly goes wrong.